# How to add VeeValidator3 errors into Bootstrap-Vue Validator

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue, vee-validate

I need to integrate Bootstrap-Vue input form control with VeeValidate. VeeValidate is working fine but I need to get the error behaviour to the text field when there is an error. Right now, I can see the error underneath the field, but the green outline remains around the text field with the check mark inside it.

[image: Text field with green rim indicating valid input, even though vee-validate registers input as invalid]

```html
  <validation-provider rules="odd" v-slot="{ errors }">
    <b-form-group
       id="fieldset-1"
       label="Last Name"
       label-for="last-name"
       :valid-feedback="errors[0]"
    >
      <b-form-input id="last-name" v-model="lastName" trim></b-form-input>
      <span class="text-danger" v-show="errors[0]">{{ errors[0] }}</span>
    </b-form-group>
  </validation-provider>
```

```js
extend('odd', {
  validate: value => {
    return value % 2 !== 0;
  },
  message: 'This field must be an odd number'
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got your `b-form-group` validation backwards. If you want Bootstrap-Vue to indicate an error in the field, then [use the `state` and `invalid-feedback` props](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-group#comp-ref-b-form-group-props), with the [`passed` flag that VeeValidate provides](https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/api/validation-provider.html):

```html
  <validation-provider rules="odd" v-slot="{ errors, passed }">
    <b-form-group
       id="fieldset-1"
       label="Last Name"
       label-for="last-name"
       :invalid-feedback="errors[0]"
       :state="passed"
    >
      <b-form-input id="last-name" v-model="lastName" trim></b-form-input>
    </b-form-group>
  </validation-provider>
```

This way, the input will show invalid when the field is failing validation, and Bootstrap-Vue will handle displaying the error by itself, instead of having to use a custom `<span>`.

Comment: Thats perfect !! Thanks for the explanation. I found something similar from the official site   hope this will be useful to others https://codesandbox.io/s/validation-components-bootstrapvue-usdwv?fontsize=14

Answer (score 0):

I think there is another approach for this problem:

```
<validation-provider name="Email" 
                     :rules="{ required: true, email: true }"
                     v-slot="validationContext">
    <b-form-group label="Email"
                  :invalid-feedback="validationContext.errors[0]">
        <b-form-input type="email" 
                      v-model="email"
                      :state="getValidationState(validationContext)" />
    </b-form-group>
</validation-provider>
```

Also you should have a method called `getValidationState` in your methods:

```
methods: {
    getValidationState({
        dirty,
        validated,
        valid = null
    }) {
        return dirty || validated ? valid : null;
    },
}
```